# Единая точка входа на nginx+php-fpm?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, php-nginx

Мне нужно, чтобы любой запрос перенаправлялся на index.php. Пробую так (взял с какого-то сайта):

```
   server {
        server_name 192.168.1.20;
        listen 80;
        root /home/abc/www;
        index index.php;
        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/home/abc/service/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }   
    }
```

При таком конфиге если я кладу рядом с index.php файл info.php, и запрашиваю его в браузере (192.168.1.20/info.php), то он выполняется. А должно было отфутболить на index.php.

Comment: А вы после внесения изменений в конфиг nginx ребутали?

Comment: Конечно, и релоад и рестарт делал.

Answer (score 1):

```
   server {
        server_name 192.168.1.20;
        listen 80;
        root /home/abc/www;
        index index.php;
        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/home/abc/service/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        }   
    }
```